# Example of attachment input for Mule 4 upload to Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, mule, attachment

I want upload file from Mule 4 to Salesforce attachments. I used Create processor with type="Attachment". What is the input structure and type of attachment for Create processor?

I've tried this Transformation before Create:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/java
---
{
    ParentId: payload.TicketAttachmentID,
    Name: "test.bin",
    Body: payload.FileData
}
```

I expect upload attachment in Salesforce. But Mule 4 returned error on Create step:

```
Internal execution exception while executing the script, this is most probably a bug, file an issue with the script and the input data.
Caused by:\njava.nio.charset.UnmappableCharacterException: Input length = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

try the following:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json  <-- this could be the issue
---
{
    ParentId: payload.TicketAttachmentID,
    Name: "test.bin",
    Body: payload.FileData
}
```